# Update TTL for a particular topic in kafka using Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Update `TTL` for a topic so records stay in the topic for 10 days. I have to do this for a particular topic only by Leaving all other topics TTL's the same, current configuration, I have to do this using `java` because I am pushing a topic to `kafka` through Java. I am setting following properties for pushing a topic to `kafka`

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_SERVERS);
props.put("acks", ACKS);
props.put("retries", RETRIES);
props.put("linger.ms", new Integer(LINGER_MS));
props.put("buffer.memory", new Integer(BUFFER_MEMORY));
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that using the `AdminClient`, following a snippet of code that get the current configuration (just for testing) and then update the "`retention.ms`" config on the topic named "`test`".

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");

AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(props);

ConfigResource resource = new ConfigResource(ConfigResource.Type.TOPIC, "test");

// get the current topic configuration
DescribeConfigsResult describeConfigsResult  =
        adminClient.describeConfigs(Collections.singleton(resource));

Map<ConfigResource, Config> config = describeConfigsResult.all().get();

System.out.println(config);

// create a new entry for updating the retention.ms value on the same topic
ConfigEntry retentionEntry = new ConfigEntry(TopicConfig.RETENTION_MS_CONFIG, "50000");
Map<ConfigResource, Config> updateConfig = new HashMap<ConfigResource, Config>();
updateConfig.put(resource, new Config(Collections.singleton(retentionEntry)));

AlterConfigsResult alterConfigsResult = adminClient.alterConfigs(updateConfig);
alterConfigsResult.all();

describeConfigsResult  = adminClient.describeConfigs(Collections.singleton(resource));

config = describeConfigsResult.all().get();

System.out.println(config);

adminClient.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for response, not able to get these classes info ( `AdminClient`, `DescribeConfigsResult`, `AlterConfigsResult`, `ConfigEntry`), I am using `pom` not getting import statements

Comment: Are you using the 0.11.0 release ? I'm using this one. The AdminClient API was introduced with latest version otherwise you can't do that from Java code.

Comment: `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
   <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>0.8.0</version>
  </dependency>`      I tried with 0.11.0 also but didnt work for me

Comment: I have uploaded my code on this github repo : https://github.com/ppatierno/kafka-playground

Comment: Btw you need "kafka-clients" as artifactId not "kafka_2.10"

Comment: here `new ConfigEntry(TopicConfig.RETENTION_MS_CONFIG, "50000")` 50000 is the time in seconds? I mean suppose If I want for 10 days then I have to give 864000.

Comment: the properties is retention.ms ... it's in milliseconds

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149698/discussion-between-sathish-kumar-and-ppatierno).