# How to alter the TTL for a particular topic in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to update the TTL of a specific Kafka topic to 10 days.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update TTL for a particular topic in kafka using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205969/update-ttl-for-a-particular-topic-in-kafka-using-java)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You previously asked about that and I already replied here : [Update TTL for a particular topic in kafka using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205969/update-ttl-for-a-particular-topic-in-kafka-using-java)

Unless you are asking to do that using Kafka tools? (And not in Java)
In this case there is the kafka-topics.sh command line tool, allowing you to do that using the --alter option.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --alter --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --config retention.ms=10000
```

Because altering using kafka-topics script could be removed in next release, you should use the kafka-configs script:

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name test --add-config retention.ms=5000
```

Comment: Thanks, Ya i want to do it without Java, so raised this question separately  question, here can we give two topics names or only 1 topic, I mean can we update TTL for multiple topics using single command like the one you mentioned?

Comment: the topic parameter is a Java regular expression. Only in this way you can update multiple topics (i.e. --topic test.* will update test1 and test2 topics).

Comment: while running above command(using  `kafka-topics`), I am getting the following excception `Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9999; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
`

Comment: I need to know what is the version of kafka you are using for running this scripts (so the kafka package you have downloaded on your PC for running such scripts) and the remote Kafka broker version.

Comment: `0.10.1.0` this is the kafka version, How do I know broker version, I mean is there any command or file where I can get/see broker version

Comment: this is the package you downloaded ok. What about the remote broker you are connecting ? You said me that the operational team is remote and you have to ask them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149788/discussion-between-sathish-kumar-and-ppatierno).

Comment: I applied TTL, I got a doubt, is that TTL applied to
-- Topic
or
-- records of that Topic.
Because my requirement is to records stay in that topic for 10 days only after that, only records will get delete not the topic

Comment: The topic won't be deleted don't worry. Just the record which stay for more then your TTL in that topic.