# Sending files like .csv through Apache Kafka

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

I am writting Bachelor about little distributed system with Apache Kafka using c#.
I need to create an app which gets csv/xls files and send them to Kafka that would be something like storage system. I suppose my app would be called a producer. Then I need another app which will receive files from Kafka and could working on further analysis.

I'm new with Kafka so I would be appreciate if someone could explain me how would it works or is it even possible. I think I stuck on a problem related to how send file as a message?

PS. Sorry for my english. It's not my native language.

Comment: This is definitely possible, although you'll want to ensure that the CSV files don't get too big - possibly Zip them on the producer before sending. We use the  the [Confluent Kafka client](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet) - it works well. Your question is however too open ended to be a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think you'll run into serious scaling issues if you store CSV files in Kafka. Based on my experience, you'll test it just fine with 1KB files, but in production you'll have 300MB files that will exceed the limits (it's primarily a messaging system, not a file storage system). You could instead send the path to the file in a shared file storage.

Comment: @DanWilson like you, I originally also saw Kafka as a middleware solution, but the Big Data crowd are actually using Kafka as a poor man's [Distributed Ledger](https://kafka.apache.org/intro#kafka_storage) by setting an indefinite TTL. The only thing left is to index the data on the topics/partitions by offset, so that stuff like files can be 'found' again without having to do an O(N) "table topic scan" :-)

Comment: @StuartLC if I publish a zipped file on topic in Kafka would it exist on that topic until his set time has passed?

Comment: @asketoo Yes, Kafka has a [topic wide TTL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45217846/314291) which is usually set when the topic is created (default is 7 days), and messages older than this TTL will be purged approximately when this time has elapsed (but don't rely on exact timing). But it's also possible to set the TTL to infinite and then nothing gets deleted (but you'll obviously need ever increasing disk space). I'm voting to close your question - it's too broad.